# get random point on a unit circle circle at (0, 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and C# and would like to write a function that returns the x and y coordinates as a Vector2 of a random point on a unit circle of at (0,0).

It looks like there's a function `UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle();` Which gets a random point inside the unit circle, and there is `UnityEngine.Random.onUnitSphere()` but how can I get a point *on* the unit circle?

Comment: find a random angle `θ` =>  `x=r*cos(θ)` and  `y=r*sin(θ)`

Comment: Or think about this differently: take the point (1,0) and rotate it around the origin by a random angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the [normalized property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-normalized.html) of the `Vector2` returned by `UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle;`. It'll return a vector that is

> the same direction but its length is 1.0.

Since you're using a unit circle, this will give you what your want. You'd also want to handle the rare case of a zero vector by defaulting that result to something valid:

```
return myVector == Vector2.zero ? Vector2.one : myVector;
```

Comment: From the answers, I like this code the most, since I believe it is the cleanest to read.

Comment: Although it is the most readable answer, `insideUnitCircle` can potentially return the zero vector which cannot be normalized (though the probability is tiny); also, two divisions, two multiplies and a square root (on top of generating the point, which also requires a square root and the usual Sin/Cos) seems unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I wouldn't dare argue this is in any way efficient but I'm also aware of Unity-related questions preferring simplicity over the most mathematically-sound solution. Also, thanks for pointing out that edge-case.

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between -π and π, and use it as an angle:

```
var a = UnityEngine.Random.value * (2 * Mathf.PI) - Mathf.PI;
var x = Mathf.Cos(a);
var y = Mathf.Sin(a);
```

Comment: random number doesn't have to be *between -π and π,* Ant double would work.

Comment: @Eser It does not have to, as long as the probability of generating each angle is the same. Otherwise, the distribution of points may not be uniform.

Comment: I'd rather use the `Mathf` class instead of `Math`, since this is using Unity's framework, which works with floating points instead of doubles.

Comment: @IanH. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this easily by getting a random angle and then use it to get the coordinates using the radius of the circle:

```cs
Vector2 GetPointOnCircle(float radius = 1) {
    float randomAngle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 2 * Mathf.PI - float.Epsilon);
    Vector2 pointOnCircle = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(randomAngle), Mathf.Sin(randomAngle)) * radius;
    return pointOnCircle;
}
```

Comment: You could also cut the `while` loop and generate a random number from the range `0` to `2 * Mathf.PI - float.Epsilon`. Also, there's no need to use a radius, since the asker states it to be a unit circle.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about `float.Epsilon`. I'd leave the argument though, just adding a default value of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just simple math. [Polar Coordinates](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarCoordinates.aspx)

Create a random number as double (θ) and use it to find the x,y

[image: Polar Coordinates]

```
Random rng = new Random();
PointF RandomOnUnitSphere(PointF center, double radius=1.0)
{
    var θ = rng.NextDouble();
    return new PointF((float)(radius * Math.Cos(θ) + center.X), 
                      (float)(radius * Math.Sin(θ) + center.Y));

}
```

Comment: While I really like the illustration and the code looks really beatiful, keep in mind that this question is specific to Unity3D, and should therefore retain Unity's types, since Unity does not have `PointF` or `new Random()`.
Secondly, may I ask why you use the symbol for theta? Obviously to point out that it is an angle, but shouldn't code refrain from containing such special characters?