# How to spawn object around a specific point with specific radius in Unity2D using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a game similar to a game called pick a lock game. However, I was struggle with spawning randomly a point around the border of circle but not in the circle. For more details, I want to spawn a gameObject at the border of a circle only but not every where in the circle.
Please help me :<
Thank you very much and have a good day!
p/s: I just a beginner to unity engine and syntax. It'll be great if you give me some advice of how to self-learning unity. Thank you so much

Comment: _[Please help with random spawn object on circle](https://forum.unity.com/threads/please-help-with-random-spawn-object-on-circle.512461/),_ Unity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I really like Dot Product. I took a random place around the reference object (which is in this case `transform.position`). Then take direction between `randomPos` and reference object. Calculated Dot Product with `Vector3.Dot()`. Take the angle between `randomPos` and our `transform.forward` with the result of Dot Product. Calculate the x and z values with Cos and Sin functions. Dot Product Angle always gives 0 to 180 values so I gave randomness to z-axis with multiply `dotProductAngle` with `(Random.value > 0.5f ? 1f : -1f)`. If you don't do this, the given random position will be always in front of the player.

**3D Space**

```
private void SpawnSphereOnEdgeRandomly3D()
        {
            float radius = 3f;
            Vector3 randomPos = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
            randomPos += transform.position;
            randomPos.y = 0f;
            
            Vector3 direction = randomPos - transform.position;
            direction.Normalize();
            
            float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, direction);
            float dotProductAngle = Mathf.Acos(dotProduct / transform.forward.magnitude * direction.magnitude);
            
            randomPos.x = Mathf.Cos(dotProductAngle) * radius + transform.position.x;
            randomPos.z = Mathf.Sin(dotProductAngle * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 1f : -1f)) * radius + transform.position.z;
            
            GameObject go = Instantiate(_spherePrefab, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
            go.transform.position = randomPos;
        }
```

Example in 3D

[image: UnitySpawnObjectOnEdgeRandomly3D]

**2D Space**

```
private void SpawnSphereOnEdgeRandomly2D()
{
    float radius = 3f;
    Vector3 randomPos = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
    randomPos += transform.position;
    randomPos.y = 0f;
    
    Vector3 direction = randomPos - transform.position;
    direction.Normalize();
    
    float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, direction);
    float dotProductAngle = Mathf.Acos(dotProduct / transform.forward.magnitude * direction.magnitude);
    
    randomPos.x = Mathf.Cos(dotProductAngle) * radius + transform.position.x;
    randomPos.y = Mathf.Sin(dotProductAngle * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 1f : -1f)) * radius + transform.position.y;
    randomPos.z = transform.position.z;
    
    GameObject go = Instantiate(_spherePrefab, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
    go.transform.position = randomPos;
}
```

Example in 2D

[image: UnitySpawnObjectOnEdgeRandomly2D]

I hope this helps you out

Comment: Omg, That's just what I looking for. Thanks you so much. I really feel grateful about it. sorry for my english skills that can annoy you

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something out and show were you get stuck.
I would start trying to understand point rotation with a raw language to understand what is happening, for example, point rotation in plain c#:

```
// Rotate B around A by angle theta clockwise
private static (double x, double y) Rotate(
      (double x, double y) A,
      (double x, double y) B,
      double theta)
{
        double s = Math.Sin(theta);
        double c = Math.Cos(theta);

        // translate point back to origin:
        B.x -= A.x;
        B.y -= A.y;

        // rotate point clockwise
        double xnew = B.x * c - B.y * s;
        double ynew = B.x * s + B.y * c;

        // translate point back:
        B.x = xnew + A.x;
        B.y = ynew + A.y;

        return B;
}
```

Then you can check some basic vectorial operations and their math background which is not that hard and give a look to what can be done with the unity API:
[Vector3.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html) and
[Vector3.RotateRowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html)

Sure you can figure something out.

Comment: _" I would start trying to understand point **rotation** with a raw language **to understand what is happening**"_ - who said anything about _rotation?_   Why the low level code?  Unity 3D isn't pre-OpenGL, DirectX or XNA.  When it came to actually mentioning Unity, you didn't provide an example.

Comment: From the question: "I was struggle with spawning randomly a point around the border of circle but not in the circle". I guessed I could be a good idea for the user to find the departing and destination points the OP wishes to manipulate. On the other hando no low level code (pre-OpenGL, DirectX or XNA), just plain c# that shows a 2D point rotation.

Comment: The key word in the OP's post is _"spawning"_.  You don't _"rotate"_ to an initial position.    In low level speak, only the "T" is required (and optionally a S) in the RST matrix.

Comment: to know where to spawn you need to calclulate that position, do you? Bringing it to the low level by you, not me, to apply the translation T you need to know the destination point. That indeed is out of the scope of OP's question.

Comment: [In case you missed it.  Look!  No rotations](https://forum.unity.com/threads/please-help-with-random-spawn-object-on-circle.512461/#post-3352447)

Comment: that will be useful for the OP. Needs to handle rotations/polar coords under the hood. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678042/get-random-point-on-a-unit-circle-circle-at-0-0) might also be useful for the OP